# Subir archivos a DB mysql con NodeJS

Tags: mysql, nodejs, archivo

Sé que no es una buena práctica pero debo hacerlo así si o si. 
Me piden subir archivos(pdf, xls, imagenes, etc) directamente a la DB a un campo BLOB. He visto en internet pero veo mucho con PHP pero nuestra aplicación está hecha en Angular y NodeJS.

Comment: Que haz intentado? Adjunta tu código

Comment: Te dejo este [enlace](https://www.technicalkeeda.com/nodejs-tutorials/nodejs-store-image-into-mysql-database) espero te sirva :)